# Delay video (and audio) by x seconds in FFMPEG HLS Stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming, hls

I have an input `HLS stream stream.m3u8` using my macbook camera by running:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation ^
   -framerate 30 -i 0  ^
   -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 128k ^
   -ac 2 -crf 5 -preset veryfast -hls_time 1 ^
   -g 30 -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_init_time 1 ^
   -hls_list_size 180 -hls_delete_threshold 180  ^
   -hls_flags delete_segments -hls_start_number_source datetime stream.m3u8
```

I want to use FFMPEG to create another HLS stream `stream-60.m3u8` in which the video is delayed by an arbitrary amount of seconds, e.g. 30s.

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 30 -i ./stream.m3u8 -c copy stream-60.m3u8
```

But the video delay is around 5s.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the time syntax [-]hh:mm:ss[.xxx]?

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 00:00:30.0000 -i ./stream.m3u8 -c copy stream-60.m3u8
```

Comment: Yes, the offset is still fixed to ~5s

Comment: Go with me for a second. If it's only 5secs when sent to 30secs, try setting it to 55secs. I'm wondering if it's only doing 5secs delay that you are seeing b/c of the streaming process (AKA something else is causing a 25sec delay). At least this way you could troubleshoot it.

Comment: I tested out various times and it is always ~5s of delay

Comment: I'm sure you have already tested to make sure you are running the latest version of FFMPEG. If you are on a Linux Distro you could look at pulling the source and recompile. It could be how the config was done on the compiled version.